# Convert string to mode_t

Tags: c, linux, string, permissions, mode

I have a character string "rwxrwxrwx".

How can I convert it to type mode_t to use in a chmod system call?  The permissions should be -rwxrwxrwx.

Comment: If the permission string is constant `"rwxrwxrwx"`, you could simply write `0777` or the extensive and cumbersome combination of bits from the constants defined in `<unistd.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code. However, it can be shortened with a for loop and some modulos.

```
const char *perm = "rwxrwxrwx";
mode_t mode = 0;

if (perm[0] == 'r')
  mode |= 0400;
if (perm[1] == 'w')
  mode |= 0200;
if (perm[2] == 'x')
  mode |= 0100;
if (perm[3] == 'r')
  mode |= 0040;
if (perm[4] == 'w')
  mode |= 0020;
if (perm[5] == 'x')
  mode |= 0010;
if (perm[6] == 'r')
  mode |= 0004;
if (perm[7] == 'w')
  mode |= 0002;
if (perm[8] == 'x')
  mode |= 0001;
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally it works! :)

Comment: I'd like this answer even better if it checked the length using e.g. `strspn(perm, "-rwxST")`, skipped the initial `-` or `d` (for directory flag) if ten characters long, and used the symbolic constants `S_IRUSR`, `S_IWUSR`, `S_IXUSR`, and so on, respectively, as described in the [`man 2 open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) man page. There are also three other bits that can be set: `S_ISUID` for `??S??????` (set-user-id), `S_ISGID` for `?????S???` (set-group-id),  and `S_ISVTX` for `????????T` (sticky).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with a single expression:

```
const char *perm = "rwxrwxrwx";
mode_t mode = (((perm[0] == 'r') * 4 | (perm[1] == 'w') * 2 | (perm[2] == 'x')) << 6) |
              (((perm[3] == 'r') * 4 | (perm[4] == 'w') * 2 | (perm[5] == 'x')) << 3) |
              (((perm[6] == 'r') * 4 | (perm[7] == 'w') * 2 | (perm[8] == 'x')));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)